# DNS question and Google PageRank from domains

Tags: dns, pagerank, no-www

I'm not so good at DNS at all but I do know some basics.

A while ago i have noticed, that my blog have different Page Ranks, PR 3 for domain `www.example.com` and PR 1 for domain `example.com`.

In dns records i have this setup:

```
A - IP - `www.example.com`
A - same IP - `example.com`
```

Should i replace this record "A - same IP - `example.com`" with row with CNAME instead of A?
Like that:

```
CNAME - same IP - `example.com` - alias `www.example.com`
```

Will this combine Page Rank value of both domains?

Or i can just create 302 redirection inside .htaccess file, verify example.com(without www) inside Google Webmaster Tools as my domain and inside `www.example.com` options set as main domain?

Thanks ;)

Comment: This would be better asked on webmasters and doesn't actually have anything to do with dns. :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a 301 redirect on one of your domains to point to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is "with or without .www" you can use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) to warn Google that both are the same website.

Or, you can use a permanent redirect to move traffic to the preferred form of the website name.

Or, if you don't want to use a single URL, but you want to warn search engines of the uniqueness of the content, you can use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).